# Copying hidden folders from Windows 10 to Mac OS X

Tags: node.js, windows, macos, webpack

I am moving my nodejs development from Windows 10 to Mac OS X 10.11.3. I am only vaguely familiar with the operation of my Mac, which I hope to rectify over the coming weeks.

I copied the app folder from Windows to OS X, but it appears that the hidden folders, such as `node_modules/.bin`, are either hidden on my Mac or have not been copied at all. I opened a Terminal window and ran `ls | more` but could not see the `.bin` folder.

Can someone familiar with this procedure illuminate my dark mind?

Comment: use `ls -a` to see hiden files/folder. Use `cp -r project tofolder` to copy a project folder and avoid using graphic window.

Answer (score 0):

The answer from @platinhom is right, though since you're moving from an OS to an other there are a lot of chances that the modules in your `node_modules` directory not only contains just js files, but also binaries (which have to be compiled specifically for your OS - meaning the ones from windows won't work on Mac OS).

Since you have a `node_module/.bin` folder this is very most likely.

What you should do is, at the root of your project (where there should be a package.json - **and only if there is a package.json**):

```
rm -rf ./node_modules
npm install
```

This will reinstall the modules declared in the `package.json` from the npm registry.